# How to find children elements in Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, children

I have a table like this:

```
<table data-test='container-component-table'>
  <tr data-test='container-component-table-column-names'>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried to get the children of `container-component-table-column-names` by writing

> expect(wrapper.find('container-component-table-column-names').children().length).toBe(3)

but it not working. It found zero children elements. Anyone know why?

Comment: what's `wrapper`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth `const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);`

Comment: Please provide all required information. What's the code of `Component`? Add it to your question please.